# What's the python syntax for assigning scalar coordinates in xarray?

Tags: python-xarray

I'm working with a netCDF file that has both logical (1,2,3...) and physical coordinates (lat, on).

I know that I have to assign multidimensional coordinates in xarray, but I can't find the syntax.

The goal is to produce an array dataset like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('rasm').load()
ds
```

Where xc and yc are my physical coordinates. This is where I am so far (it's obviously unfinished):

```
no2_da = xr.DataArray(no2[0],
                      dims=("x",
                            "y"),
                      coords={
                          "lat": ("x",scanline)
                          "lon": ()
                      }

                     )
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your can use this format

```
no2[0] = 15 + 10 * np.random.randn(size)# value of no2[0]
lat = np.random.uniform(low=-90, high=90, size=size)#your latitude here
lon = np.random.uniform(low=-180, high=180, size=size)#your longitude here

# round to two digits after decimal point
no2[0], lat, lon = np.around([no2[0], lat, lon], decimals=2)

df = pd.DataFrame({"no2[0]": no2[0], "lat": lat, "lon": lon})
```